# how to test props which is pass through Link in react router with React-testing-library or jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

how do I test props which is pass to other page
as given below I have created a object of name merchant which need to be passed to other page which I am passing as a props in Link.
and accessing value using **useLocation** and setting to dropdown

```
const {merchantData} = useLocation();
```

I want to write a test case for this, but how to test it which has passed as props

```
const merchant = {
value:"abc123",
label:"abc",
data:{
   id:1,
   name:abc
  }
}
<Link to={{ pathname: `/administration/person/add`,merchantData: merchant }}> Create Person</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mock `history.push` in your test, then click on your `Link`, and expect that `history.push` has been called, with the correct parameters :

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('my component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    history.push = jest.fn();
  });

  it('passes correct parameters when following the link', () => {
    rtl = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <MyComponent />
      </Router>
    );

    // we assume that MyComponent contains the Link you provided
    userEvent.click(rtl.getByText('Create Person'));
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      pathname: '/administration/person/add',
      merchantData: { /* your object */ }
    });
  });
});
```

But you should pass additional informations in the state property of the `to` props : https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/administration/person/add`, state: { merchant } }}>Create Person</Link>
```

If you do so, you will need to modify the above test accordingly.